# VBA runtime error 9 when defining sheets by name within a workbook

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I am creating a macro to add some info from input sheets to a master sheet in a different workbook. When it comes to defining the sheets in one of the workbooks, I get error 9. It has happened both when trying to define them by index number and by name. Here is the code itself:

```
'1. Definiendo el archivo de nóminas

    Dim nominas_wb          As Workbook
    Dim nominas_path        As Variant
    
    
    nominas_path = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Seleccione un archivo de nóminas que desee añadir al repositorio:")
    If nominas_path = False Then
        MsgBox ("La acción ha sido terminada. Si desea iniciarla de nuevo abra un archivo de nóminas, por favor :).")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set nominas_wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=nominas_path)
    End If

    Dim nominas_ws1         As worksheet
    Set nominas_ws1 = nominas_wb.Worksheets(1)
    
'2. Definiendo el archivo de repositorio
    
    Dim repositorio_wb          As Workbook
    Dim repositorio_path        As Variant
    
    
    repositorio_path = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Seleccione el repositorio de nóminas:")
    If repositorio_path = False Then
        MsgBox ("La acción ha sido terminada. Si desea iniciarla de nuevo seleccione el repositorio de nóminas, por favor (@_J@).")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set repositorio_wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=nominas_path)
    End If
    
    Dim repositorio_ws1     As worksheet
    Dim repositorio_ws2     As worksheet
    Dim repositorio_ws3     As worksheet
    Dim repositorio_ws4     As worksheet
    
    Set repositorio_ws1 = repositorio_wb.Worksheets("repositorio") %%% error 9 here %%%
    Set repositorio_ws2 = repositorio_wb.Worksheets("conceptos")
    Set repositorio_ws3 = repositorio_wb.Worksheets("imputaciones")
    Set repositorio_ws4 = repositorio_wb.Worksheets("cuentas")

'x. Cerrando los archivos
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    nominas_wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    repositorio_wb.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
'z. Mensajes y errores
    
    Dim x As String
        x = "x"
    MsgBox "Se han creado " & x & " nuevas entradas en el repositorio de nóminas."
```

And here is a view of the workbook referenced by the line that is throwing the error:

[image: repositorio_wb]

Comment: Error 9 means that there is no worksheet with that name in the workbook.  Check if the sheet name includes leading or trailing spaces

Comment: Thank you @chrisneilsen for the insight but, I have already checked that and everything seems to add up. Same name, no spaces, everything is the same as far as I can tell.

Comment: A very odd thing just happened. I commented out the line itself and I got an error from the .Save method near the bottom of the sub. I then ran the code again and it seems to work fine, no more error 9. Any idea on how to save the workbook without causing any issues?

Comment: Sometimes inexplicable behavior like this is caused by corrupt Workbooks.   Maybe try rebuilding the workbook.